# Cancelling a constant running async task in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

We have a system set up that:

1. Begins with creating an async task that wraps a function. This function runs a `while True` loop and constantly creates and awaits/gathers async tasks while running.
2. We want to maintain the ability to independently cancel these children async tasks.
3. We also want to maintain the ability to cancel the parent task, with the `while True` loop and its children.

With this in mind, we're struggling to set up our cancellations such that the parent task is actually cancelled and all work is stopped. Rather the behavior we see is an infinite loop.

I'm attaching a dummy code example of this below:

```
import asyncio


async def runner(container):
    print(f"Executing Runner")
    iter = 0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Creating task")

        new_tasks = [
            asyncio.create_task(unit_of_work(), name=f"unit_of_work-{iter}"),
            asyncio.create_task(unit_of_work(), name=f"unit_of_work-{iter+1}"),
        ]
        iter += 2
        container.extend(new_tasks)

        try:
            await asyncio.gather(*container)
        except asyncio.CancelledError as ce:
            print(
                f"catching cancellation. Cancellations: {[i.cancelled() for i in new_tasks]}"
            )
            print(f"\nNew tasks: {new_tasks}\n\n")


async def unit_of_work():
    task = asyncio.current_task()
    name = None
    if task:
        name = task.get_name()
    step = 0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        print(f"{name} doing some work, step - {step}")
        step += 1


async def task_create():
    cancellables = []
    t = asyncio.create_task(runner(cancellables), name="runner")
    return t, cancellables


async def cancel(t):
    t.cancel()


async def main():
    t, cancellables = await task_create()

    await asyncio.sleep(2)

    for c in cancellables:
        c.cancel(f"Cancelling: {c.get_name()}")

    t.cancel(f"Cancelling {t.get_name()}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: `iter` is a python builtin, and your code is redefining it. This is not part of your current problem, but it is an issue.

Comment: Sure - not defined as such in actual code, just in this quickly typed dummy example.

Answer (score 0):

Look into asyncio primitives - they'll open new paradigms that are extremely useful in asyncio-land. Example below is using [`asyncio.Event()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event), but one could've also used `asyncio.Future()` (non-primitive, but nonetheless...).

```py
import asyncio

async def runner(tasks: list, event: asyncio.Event):
    num = 0
    while not event.is_set():
        task = asyncio.create_task(unit_of_work(), name=f"task-{num}")
        tasks.append(task)

        num += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    print("Runner is done. Cancelling tasks...")

    for task in tasks:
        if task.cancelled():
            print(f"Task {task.get_name()} was already cancelled")
            continue
        print(f"Cancelling {task.get_name()}")
        task.cancel()

async def unit_of_work():
    task = asyncio.current_task()
    name = task.get_name() if task else "<unknown>"

    while True:
        print(f"Unit of work from {name}")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def main():
    event, tasks = asyncio.Event(), []
    parent = asyncio.create_task(runner(tasks, event))

    # Cancel the first task after 1 second just cause.
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    first_task = tasks[0]
    print(f"Cancelling {first_task.get_name()}")
    first_task.cancel()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f"Cancelled {first_task.get_name()} - {first_task.cancelled()}")

    # Wait 3 seconds and stop the runner.
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    event.set()

    # Wait for runner to finish and execute cleanup.
    await parent

    print("Done.")

asyncio.run(main())
```

```
Unit of work from task-0
Cancelling task-0
Unit of work from task-1
Cancelled task-0 - True
Unit of work from task-2
Unit of work from task-1
Unit of work from task-3
Unit of work from task-2
Unit of work from task-4
Unit of work from task-1
Unit of work from task-3
Runner is done. Cancelling tasks...
Task task-0 was already cancelled
Cancelling task-1
Cancelling task-2
Cancelling task-3
Cancelling task-4
Done.
```

Comment: Would you happen to know why the approach we leveraged doesn't work?

Comment: You are trying gather *all* the tasks inside the `cancellables`/`container` list on every loop iteration in your runner when you don't need to do that - `asyncio.create_task()` already schedules those tasks to be ran. Delete the entire `try`/`except` inside the `runner`, and fix the `X.cancel(...)` calls inside your `main()` to just be `c.cancel()` and `t.cancel()`.

Comment: I did that to simplify the code, I'm updating the code snippet to be more representative.

Comment: It didn't simplify the code - it broke it. Regarding the `X.cancel()` you can ignore that comment. Just realized the function takes in a `msg`, so those are good.

Answer (score -1):

`await asyncio.gather(*container)` seems the problem,  because it makes all the tasks wait to complete before proceeding.

Try use `asyncio.create_task()` to run your worker unit (`unit_of_work`) and keep track of it's cancellation status

Comment: The worker unit `unit_of_work` does leverage `create_task` for creation. `container` is an array of `asyncio.Task` objects.